# How to Integrate $\frac{x}{(x^{2}+1)^2}$ by integral properties only

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate $\int\frac{x}{(x^{2}+1)^2}$, but without using a methods like the subtitution method, itegration by parts, etc.. 
I am trying to calculate it using the Integral properties only and I can't find a way to simplify the problem. any hints?

Comment: Which integral properties are allowed?

Comment: Since when are substitution method and integration by parts not integral properties?

Comment: 'I want to tennis without a tennis racquet'

Comment: Notice that this integral has form $-\frac 12 \int{-f'(x)\over (f(x))^2}$...

Comment: This is in fact a perfect example for substitution, as the derivative of the denominator is in the numerator (only differing by a constant).

Comment: I assume you mean integration with respect to $x$. (You should not forget the $dx$)

Comment: The function is quite clearly the derivative of $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}$. What “using the integral properties” mean is not clear at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do long division of polynomials, but keep going and use negative powers of $x$ to get

$$\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2} = x -2x^3+3x^5-4x^7+\cdots.$$

Then integrate term by term (assuming convergence) to get

$$\int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2} \; dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^4 +\frac{1}{2}x^6 +\cdots .$$

Then notice that this is a geometric series with sum

$$\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

And when you protest that this isn't the right answer, I will respond, "Yes it is, you just have to adjust the constant of integration."